# Using circular permutations to reduce Traveling Salesman complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, circular-permutations

I'm trying out a bunch of different algorithms for finding near-optimal solutions to the [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), and one of the methods is the brute force approach - checking *every* possible path between n cities, and simply returning the best one. This is an O(n!) algorithm, so naturally it takes a very long time to execute for a large number of cities.

I want to improve the efficiency of my brute force implementation, and one of the things I've noticed is that you don't have to check *every* single permutation of the cities. For example, if you have cities 1, 2, 3, and 4, the path (1-2-3-4) is the same length as path (2-3-4-1). The same goes for the paths (3-4-1-2) and (4-1-2-3). By exploiting this fact, we should be able to reduce the complexity of the brute force algorithm from O(n!) to O((n-1)!), or even O((n-1)!/2) if we realize that all paths can be reversed without affecting their lengths.

Basically, I'm looking for an algorithm that is capable of generating [circular permutations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularPermutation.html) from a set of distinct integers. It would also be great if the algorithm treated "mirrored" permutations as equivalent (e.g. 1-2-3 and 3-2-1 are the same, so only one of them is needed). Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this? A Java implementation would be wonderful, but I'll take anything!

Comment: It is same as generating a factorial from n-1 instead of n. Will this accomplish your objective?

Comment: @UVM Generating permutations on n-1 cities will not solve my problem. I need to generate a list of permutations on n cities that excludes repeated paths (whether they be cyclic or reversed).

Comment: You can try graph theory. Please check this link.http://web.info.uvt.ro/~mmarin/lectures/GTC/c-10.pdf

Comment: (1-2-3) is the same length than (2-3-1), but also the same length than (3-2-1), right? So actually any combination of three given cities will always have the same length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you always start with the same node (for example '1') you should never run into this problem. Then you can easily add a check for mirrors as well because that is just running from node 0 to N-1 N-2 until you are at zero again.

For example, 1,2,3,4 has the following permutations:

```
1234 1243 1324 1342 1423 1432 2134 2143 2314 2341 2413 2431
3124 3142 3214 3241 3412 3421 4123 4132 4213 4231 4312 4321
```

Now if we force 1 as first node, you'll end up with these unique solutions:

```
1234 1243 1324 1342 1423 1432
```

Next we can eliminate the 'mirrored' solutions:

```
normal => reverse => rotated by 1
1234 => 4321 => 1432
1243 => 3421 => 1342
1324 => 4231 => 1423
```

You'll only need to check:

```
1234 1243 1324
```

**Update:**

The easiest way to generate this sequence is to enumerate all possibilities of 1 ... N-1 where 1 is before 2 (forcing direction) and appending N.

For example for N=4, we first generate all permutations 1 ... N-1:

```
123 132 213 231 312 321
```

Now we filter where 1 is before 2:

```
123 132 312
```

And append N (4):

```
1234 1324 3124
```

This is probably easier and more efficient to program. This also proves the upper bound needed to brute force TSP is: (N - 1)! / 2

Answer (score 0):

You can try the zip method, it looks promising:[http://web.archive.org/web/20110817142304/http://www.jochen-pleines.de/english/34_nkl.htm](http://web.archive.org/web/20110817142304/http://www.jochen-pleines.de/english/34%5fnkl.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I know you're talking about marginal optimization, but in terms of time complexity, it's worth noting that O(n!) and O((n−1)!/2) are asymptotically equivalent.

To generate circular permutations while treating mirrored permutations as equivalent, you can leverage Satollo's algorithm:

https://danluu.com/sattolo/

https://doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(86)90073-6